# Scotty Convert GET Parameter / Lazy.Text conversion

Tags: haskell, scotty

I try to pass a GET parameter into a function and concat a string from the result

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Web.Scotty

f x = x <> x
main = do
  scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/f/:x" $ do
        x <- param "x"
        text ("f(" <> x <> ") = " <> f x)
```

To make my application even more interesting, I want to use a function which requires an argument type instance of Num, e.g.

```
f x = x * x
```

How can I convert/read `x` to a `Num` (or `Maybe...`) and convert the function result back to a `Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text`?

I tried

```
text ("f(" <> x <> ") = " <> (show $ f $ read x))
```

which yields errors:

```
• Couldn't match expected type
  ‘text-1.2.3.1:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
  with actual type ‘[Char]’
```

Comment: `Text` is not the same as `String`, and this has bitten a lot of people, not only in Haskell. You will likely need to `import qualified Data.Text as T` and then use `T.pack` function to convert `String` (_i.e._, `[Char]`) to `Data.Text` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Bob Dalgleish (comments) for helping me on this problem, with `pack`/`unpack` functions I could solve the situation

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as L
import Web.Scotty

f x = x * x
main = do
  scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/f/:x" $ do
        x <- param "x"
        let res_string = show $ f $ read $ T.unpack x
        let label_string = "f(" <> (T.unpack x) <> ") = "
        text $ L.pack (label_string <> res_string)
```

Please note that `read` is "dangerous" and should not be replaced by `readMaybe`, but this would be off topic here.